# Trigger to copy record from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, triggers

I have following table:

**TableStaff**

```
UserId, Username, Firstname, Lastname
1001 CLWA Clara Wallace
1002 RITA Ricky Tate
1003 PAEV Pat Evans
```

**TableFeatures**

```
UserId, Feature, Notes, LogDate
1001 901 Note1 2018-06-15
1002 905 Note111 2018-06-17
1003 903 Note222 2018-06-18
```

**TableExport**

```
UserId, Username, Firstname, Lastname, Feature, Notes
1001 CLWA Clara Wallace 901 Note1    
1002 RITA Ricky Tate 905 Note111
1003 PAEV Pat Evans 903 Note222
```

We have a front end application from where we can select the user and the feature which then gets inserted into the **TableFeatures**. 
Every time the new record gets inserted I want that new record to be inserted to the **TableExport**.

Everyday at 10:00pm a schedule job will export the data from the **TableExport** to the CSV then the table gets truncated.

I am not sure how to create a trigger that can copy the **Username, Firstname, Lastname** along with the **UserId, Feature, Notes**

I have following trigger that only copies **UserId, Feature, Notes** from the **TableFeatures**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_TableFeatures ON TableFeatures
FOR INSERT 
AS
INSERT INTO TableExport (UserId, Feature, Notes)
SELECT UserId, Feature, Notes from Inserted
GO
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you to not to create trigger. When you insert data into TableFeatures, insert data into TableExport also. You have all the relevant columns and it will be easier to insert and better design. Instead of depending on trigger to do the insert for you.

Comment: The first thing I see it, I don't think you need all those columns in `TableExport`, that's my note, and for the `trigger` you could create one on `TableFeatures` with a simple `SELECT` and join with `TableStaff` table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just need a `JOIN`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_TableFeatures ON TableFeatures
FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableExport (UserId, Username, Firstname, Lastname, Feature, Notes)
        SELECT i.UserId, s.Username, s.Firstname, s.Lastname, i.Feature, i.Notes 
        FROM Inserted i JOIN
             TableStaff s
             ON i.UserId = s.UserId
END;
```

Comment: it complains about: Ambiguous column name 'UserId'. I have tried TableFeatures.UserId or TableStaff.UserId, which throws another error "The multi-part identifier "TableFeatures.UserId" could not be bound."

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer is correct only, you just need a join, since you mentioned about the error, i tried that myself on sql sever 2016 it works fine for me. Here is the code.

```
   insert into TabelExport
   (userid,username,firstname,
   lastname,feature,notes)
   select  i.userid,ts.username,
   ts.firstname,
   ts.lastname,i.features,
   i.notes 
   from inserted i 
   inner join TableStaff ts 
   on (i.userid=ts.userid);
```